# Variants or Polymorphic variants?

Tags: types, programming-languages, functional-programming, ocaml, ml

I noticed that, among OCaml programmers I know, some of them *always* use polymorphic variants (variants that are not declared, prefixed with a backquote), while other ones *never* use polymorphic variants, and prefer variants declared in types.

Except for performance reasons (polymorphic variants are currently compiled less efficiently than simple variants), how do expert OCaml developers choose between them ?

Comment: I think the preferred name is "open variants" now.

Comment: "open variant" is clearly easier to undertand intuitively then "polymorphic variant"

Comment: I think "open variant" more accurately refers to types like `exn`.

Comment: Stating the obvious: plain ADT are not exactly equivalent type wise to polymorphic variants: if you need the specific properties of the later, obviously you'll have to use them (ie. overlapping enum sets in your data types, subtyping via row polymorphism).

Comment: Real World Ocaml has an [entire section on this](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/variants.html#when-to-use-polymorphic-variants).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

My usage can be divided into the following 5 categories. 1. interface 2. modularity 3. legibility 4. brevity 5. tricks

1. If the variant type is only internal to the module, I use regular variants, because as you said they are compiled more efficiently.
2. If the variant type is exported in the interface and I feel that some cases could appear in other modules but it wouldn't necessarily make sense to make them dependend on the module, I use polymorphic variants because they are not tied to the module namespace system. Examples: the [encoding type](http://erratique.ch/software/xmlm/doc/Xmlm#TYPEencoding) type of `Xmlm`. Also having the [signal type](http://erratique.ch/software/xmlm/doc/Xmlm#TYPEsignal) as a variant type means you can develop modules using the same idea for XML processing without introducing a dependency on `Xmlm`.
3. If the variant type is exported in the interface I find it sometimes too verbose to use regular variants when values of the variant type are given to functions of the module. Example: the [version type](http://erratique.ch/software/uuidm/doc/Uuidm#TYPEversion) of `Uuidm`. Instead of having to write `Uuidm.create Uuidm.V4` you can simply write `` Uuidm.create `V4 ``, which is as clear and less verbose.
4. Sometimes a particular function may return different cases. If these cases are only used by this function I declare the function type in the interface without having to introduce a type definition. For example `` parse : string -> [`Error of string | `Ok of t] ``
5. Polymorphic variants and their subtyping allow you enforce invariants statically with phantom types. Besides the possibility of defining them incrementally can be useful, both for enforcing invariants statically and for documentation purposes.

Finally I sometimes use polymorphic variants in the implementation of a module according to 4. but without them showing up in the interface. I discourage this usage unless you declare the polymorphic variants and close them because it weakens the static typing discipline.

Comment: Great summary. This should be in some FAQ.

Answer (score 17):

The only reason why I use polymorphic variants in most module interfaces is to work around the naming issues of classic variants.

If the following could work, polymorphic variants would no longer be useful in a majority of cases:

```
type t1 = String of string | Int of int | Bool of bool | List of t1 list
type t2 = String of string | Int of int | Other

let simplify x =
  match (x : t1) with
      String s -> String s
    | Int n -> Int n
    | Bool _
    | List _ -> Other
```

2014-02-21 Update: the code above is now valid in OCaml 4.01. Hurray!

Comment: For the benefit of those who come after me to read on this very topic of when to use polymorphic variants: Martin's example is finally legal in OCaml 4.01. Rejoice!

Answer (score 13):

It's not true that polymorphic variants are always less efficient. Using Martin's example:

```
type base = [`String of string | `Int of int]
type t1 = [base | `Bool of bool | `List of t1 list]
type t2 = [base | `Other]

let simplify (x:t1):t2 = match x with
| #base as b -> b
| `Bool _ | `List _ -> `Other
```

To do this with standard variants requires two distinct types and a complete recoding, with polymorphic variants the base case is physically invariant. This feature really comes into its own when using open recursion for term rewriting:

```
type leaf = [`String of string | `Int of int]
type 'b base = [leaf | `List of 'b list]
type t1 = [t1 base | `Bool of bool ]
type t2 = [t2 base | `Other]

let rec simplify (x:t1):t2 = match x with
| #leaf as x -> x
| `List t -> `List (List.map simplify t)
| `Bool _ -> `Other
```

and the advantages are even greater when the rewriting functions are also factored with open recursion.

Unfortunately Ocaml's Hindley-Milner type inference is not strong enough to do this kind of thing without explicit typing, which requires careful factorisation of the types, which in turn makes proto-typing difficult. Additionally, explicit coercions are sometimes required.

The big downside of this technique is that for terms with multiple parameters, one soon ends up with a rather confusing combinatorial explosion of types, and in the end it is easier to give up on static enforcement and use a kitchen sink type with wildcards and exceptions (i.e. dynamic typing).