# When should extensible variant types be used in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I took a course on OCaml before [extensible variant types](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.07/extn.html#sec266) were introduced, and I don't know much about them.  I have several questions:

1. (This question was deleted because it attracted a "not answerable objectively" close vote.)
2. What are the low-level consequences of using EVTs, such as performance, memory representation, and (un-)marshaling?

Note that my question is about *extensible* variant type specifically, unlike the question suggested as identical to this one (that question was asked prior to the introduction of EVTs!).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variants or Polymorphic variants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367181/variants-or-polymorphic-variants)

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're talking about? Is it related to this [pull request](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/1253)? Previously, polymorphic variants were also called "open variants" because they are open to extension, so it is not a stretch to assume that one might call them "extensible variants". If you're talking about the new feature, adding a code example would help for clarity. (I had flagged as possible duplicate but I have retracted the flag.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extensible variants are quite different from standard variants in term of
runtime behavior.

In particular, extension constructors are runtime values that lives inside
the module where they were defined. For instance, in

```
 type t = ..
 module M = struct
   type t +=A
 end
 open M
```

the second line define a new extension constructor value `A` and add it to the
existing extension constructors of `M` at runtime.
Contrarily, classical variants do not really exist at runtime.

It is possible to observe this difference by noticing that I can use
a mli-only compilation unit for classical variants:

```
 (* classical.mli *)
 type t = A

 (* main.ml *)
 let x = Classical.A
```

and then compile `main.ml` with

> ocamlopt classical.mli main.ml

without troubles because there are no value involved in the `Classical` module.

Contrarily with extensible variants, this is not possible. If I have

```
 (* ext.mli *)
  type t = ..
  type t+=A

 (* main.ml *)
 let x = Ext.A
```

then the command

> ocamlopt ext.mli main.ml

fails with

> Error: Required module `Ext' is unavailable

because the runtime value for the extension constructor `Ext.A` is missing.

You can also peek at both the name and the id of the extension constructor
using the `Obj` module to see those values

```
 let a = [%extension_constructor A]
 Obj.extension_name a;;
```

> - : string = "M.A"

```
 Obj.extension_id a;;
```

> - : int = 144

(This `id` is quite brittle and its value it not particurlarly meaningful.)
An important point is that extension constructor are distinguished using their
memory location. Consequently, constructors with `n` arguments are implemented
as block with `n+1` arguments where the first hidden argument is the extension
constructor:

```
type t += B of int
let x = B 0;;
```

Here, `x` contains two fields, and not one:

```
 Obj.size (Obj.repr x);;
```

> - : int = 2

And the first field is the extension constructor `B`:

```
 Obj.field (Obj.repr x) 0 == Obj.repr [%extension_constructor B];;
```

> - : bool = true

The previous statement also works for `n=0`: extensible variants are never
represented as a tagged integer, contrarily to classical variants.

Since marshalling does not preserve physical equality, it means that extensible
sum type cannot be marshalled without losing their identity. For instance, doing
a round trip with

```
 let round_trip (x:'a):'a = Marshall.from_string (Marshall.to_string x []) 0
```

then testing the result with

```
  type t += C
  let is_c = function
  | C -> true
  | _ -> false
```

leads to a failure:

```
   is_c (round_trip C)
```

> - : bool = false

because the round-trip allocated a new block when reading the marshalled value
This is the same problem which already existed with exceptions, since exceptions
are extensible variants.

This also means that pattern-matching on extensible type is quite different
at runtime. For instance, if I define a simple variant

```
 type s = A of int | B of int
```

and define a function `f` as

```
let f = function
| A n | B n -> n
```

the compiler is smart enough to optimize this function to simply accessing the
the first field of the argument.

You can check with `ocamlc -dlambda` that the function above is represented in
the Lambda intermediary representation as:

```
(function param/1008 (field 0 param/1008)))
```

However, with extensible variants, not only we need a default pattern

```
   type e = ..
   type e += A of n | B of n
   let g = function
   | A n | B n -> n
   | _ -> 0
```

but we also need to compare the argument with each extension constructor in the
match leading to a more complex lambda IR for the match

```
 (function param/1009
   (catch
     (if (== (field 0 param/1009) A/1003) (exit 1 (field 1 param/1009))
       (if (== (field 0 param/1009) B/1004) (exit 1 (field 1 param/1009))
         0))
    with (1 n/1007) n/1007)))
```

Finally, to conclude with an actual example of extensible variants,
in OCaml 4.08, the Format module replaced its string-based user-defined tags
with extensible variants.

This means that defining new tags looks like this:

First, we start with the actual definition of the new tags

```
 type t =  Format.stag = ..
 type Format.stag += Warning | Error
```

Then the translation functions for those new tags are

```
let mark_open_stag tag =
match tag with
| Error -> "\x1b[31m" (* aka print the content of the tag in red *)
| Warning -> "\x1b[35m" (* ... in purple *)
| _ -> ""

let mark_close_stag _tag =
  "\x1b[0m" (*reset *)
```

Installing the new tag is then done with

```
 let enable ppf =
    Format.pp_set_tags ppf true;
    Format.pp_set_mark_tags ppf true;
    Format.pp_set_formatter_stag_functions ppf
    { (Format.pp_get_formatter_stag_functions ppf ()) with
    mark_open_stag; mark_close_stag }
```

With some helper function, printing with those new tags can be done with

```
 Format.printf "This message is %a.@." error "important"
 Format.printf "This one %a.@." warning "not so much"
```

Compared with string tags, there are few advantages:

- less room for a spelling mistake
- no need to serialize/deserialize potentially complex data
- no mix up between different extension constructor with the same name.
- chaining multiple user-defined `mark_open_stag` function is thus safe:
  each function can only recognise their own extension constructors.

Comment: Can you clarify what the memory representation is for a nullary extensible variant case ( type t += Foo )?

Comment: For nullary constructors, the internal extension constructor is used directly, i.e. `Obj.repr Foo == [%extension_constructor Foo]`.